# Creating a custom LLVM Frontned (VBS >> JS)

Tags: javascript, vbscript, llvm, frontend

I have a project where large data in VBScript needs to be converted to JS, preferably through an automated system.

Have looked at "Script Converter", good but limited usability.
Found LLVM & Emscripten, excellent solution to my issue but the frontend is Clang (C/C++)

My questions are:
1) Is there a way I can go VBS >> C/C++ >> LLVM >>JS (probably not)
2) Or any ideas as to how I could make a custom frontend that uses VBS, (went through some articles, is using lex & yacc the only options? ie. making ur own compiler)

Answer (score 0):

True, Emscripten can be used to translate C/C++ to JS via LLVM. However, I'm not sure how good a fit this will be for you. That's because C/C++ have a different programming model from JS, while the one of VBS is IMHO much closer to JS. So lowering from VBS to C++ and then going to JS sounds kind-of unnecessary.

In other words, I think that compiling VBS to JS is easier that compiling VBS to C/C++ that would be needed to leverage Emscripten/LLVM.

Now, how to compile VBS is a different question. Unless you find an existing solution, you'll need to implement a simple compiler. In your case it may suffice to create a compiler that only supports the subset of VBS your code actually uses as opposed to a fully general VBS frontend.

Comment: Thanks Eli

it makes sense not to go via the C/C++ route, will complicate things more than whats necessary.

But unfortunately have gone through internet & this forum but to my luck haven't found anything that links VBS to LLVM. (that is why wanted to know if C/C++ route is ok)

If you or other members have come across such compiler, I'll be happy to have a go at ur suggestions.

Comment: I was going through your website where you mention about Clang's parsers ability to generate AST

I have been researching a lot on this, have gone through numerous posts & forums.

Could you please suggest me a way/any tutorial that makes it easier to understand how AST & LLVM IR are connected. 
Kaleidoscope example was not to my liking, need other than C/C++ examples.

sorry for the bother but I'm a noob in this and would appreciate any help possible!

Thanks

Comment: @user2903549: this sounds like a different question